# Escape all special characters in a string that is sent by jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, text

I am trying to send text in key value pairs while doing a  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` ajax post to a web service. The problem I am facing is that if one of the parameters (that accepts text from the user) has quotes (") it breaks the code [Eror message: Invalid object passed in ] . So far I have tried these without any success

```
var text = $("#txtBody").val(); 
var output1 = JSON.stringify(text); 
var output2 = text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

Any ideas on how to escape the special characters for the jquery ajax post?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Why not use `escape`?

```
escape(text);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape

**EDIT!!!!**

As mentioned in comments, this is deprecated.

> The deprecated escape() method computes a new string in which certain characters have been replaced by a hexadecimal escape sequence. Use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent instead.

Instead use one of the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: I added an answer, because it is not a good practice to use escape method

Comment: Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Answer (score 14):

For those who will find this question:
**Do not use escape method it has been removed from the Web**
Use `encodeURIComponent()` or `encodeURI()` instead
[encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
[encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Comment: No, never use encodeURI(), it's unreliable and is based on guessing. encodeURI guess where the data name and values starts and ends based on the `&` and `=` characters, and that guess can be wrong. as a direct example, this url is incorrectly encoded by encodeURI: `encodeURI("http://example.org/?foo=i love my mother&father");` - here foo is supposed to be `i love my mother&father`, but encodeURI encodes it to `i love my mother` - meanwhile, encodeURIComponent makes 0 guesses, and works correctly here: `"http://example.org/?foo="+encodeURIComponent("i love my mother&father");`

Answer (score 4):

#### 2020 Update

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), an example pulled from MDN.

```js
// encodes characters such as ?,=,/,&,:
console.log(encodeURIComponent('?x=шеллы'));
// expected output: "%3Fx%3D%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"

console.log(encodeURIComponent('?x=test'));
// expected output: "%3Fx%3Dtest"
```

[encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) which expects a *complete URI* could be worth a look as well.

My previous suggestion was to use `escape()` method, but now that it has been deprecated and soon will be dropped as well.

> Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code
>
> More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: Your answer worked for me Starx. But unfortunately they don't let me mark more than one answer. Sorry :(

Comment: This function was deprecated in JS.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, and to solve it, I change the way I was making the ajax call.

I had something like

```
var datatosend = "Hello+World";

$.ajax({
    "type": "POST", 
    "data": "info=" + datatosend
```

And it send on the post info=Hello World, replacing the character + with a blank space.

So I change it into a correct json string

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST", 
    "data": {"info":datatosend},
```

and now it works. info=Hello+World

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Do not use `escape()`***.  Source: [**MDN `escape()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)...

> Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours...

2. ***Do not use `encodeURI()`***. *(Alternative listed below.)*  Source: [**MDN `encodeURI()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> If one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs... the following code snippet may help:
>
> `function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>       return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
>   }`

3. ***Do not use `encodeURIComponent()`.***  *(Alternative listed below.)*  Source: [**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:
>
> `function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>     return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>       return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>     });
>   }`

So, if you want to encode all data except for these operators: `+@?=:#;,$&`, use `fixedEncodeURI()`.  If you want to include those characters (which are used in defining `GET` parameters, and other uses), then use `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`.