# PHP function does not display string after "&"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using CI and windows 7.
From my view file I am calling a function in ajax which is in controller.
In my ajax I am passing a string as `Pack & Send`, but when I echo same string in controller function it is just echoing `Pack`.

My ajax call looks like

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#items").change(function(){
            var country_id =  $("select#items option:selected").attr('value'); 
            $("#state").html( "" );
            $("#city").html( "" );
            if (country_id.length > 0 ) { 
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('ga_api/sample/ajax_second_dropdown');?>",
                    data: "country_id="+country_id,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () { 
                        $('#state').html('<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH;?>loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                    },
                    success: function(html) {    
                        $("#state").html( html );
                    }
                });
            } 
          alert(country_id);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

On alert i get entire string i.e. `Pack & Send`.

Now my php function in controller

```
function ajax_second_dropdown()
{
    echo $_POST["country_id"]; 
}
```

Here it just echos `Pack`

I thought may be due to special character. But I guess that is not the scene as I tried to change `&` to , `%`, `'`, `\`, `\&`  and so on, in these cases I get entire string.

Comment: Try to URL encode the string before passing it to ajax. Does it work when you remove the `&`?

Comment: Try this.

`data: "country_id="+encodeURI(country_id),`

Comment: jQuery accepts object for its data setting, so you can let it do the escaping: `data: {"country_id": country_id},`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` *is* a special character: it's used in [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). For example, `?var1=x&var2=y`.

You need to URL-encode your variable before sending it over HTTP:

```
data: "country_id="+encodeURIComponent(country_id),
```

Comment: I don't understand, in your example `country_id` is similar to `var1` in your first example. So there won't be a `&` since there is only parameter?

Comment: @A.L correct. But if there's an `&` in the _variable_ `country_id`, the second part (after the `&`) will be seen as `var2`.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. I was confused by the fact that `country_id` should be a number (like the majority of ids), not a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have the same problem as this question : [Escape all special characters in a string that is sent by jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133082/escape-all-special-characters-in-a-string-that-is-sent-by-jquery-ajax)

The "&" is a special character and you need to escape him (I'm not sure for the space character but it's same). Use this function (encodeURIComponent) that escape all character except  alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Here is the documentation : [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Your code :

```
data:"country_id="+encodeURIComponent(country_id),
```